# How can I optimize the code by replacing the for loop in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, azure-databricks

I must implement the below function on all the columns in my data frame. But using for loop is detrimental to spark performance, how can I avoid using for loop and still have the same logic and output? My function takes a data frame and returns a data frame with the column name and required statistics for each column.

Here is the function:

```
def get_null_count_and_percentage(df):
   
   columnList = df.columns
   total_count = df.count()
   null_counts = []
   for column_to_check in columnList:      
        null_count = df.filter(col(column_to_check).isNull()).count()
        null_perentage = (null_count / total_count) * 100
        null_counts.append((column_to_check, null_count, null_perentage))     
   result_df_count = (
     spark.createDataFrame(null_counts, ["column_name", "null_counts", "null_percentage"])
    .withColumn("null_percentage", round(col("null_percentage"), 3))
     )
   return result_df_count
```

I tried to find, but couldn't find exact solution for my problem. I tried map, reduce etc. but those couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: have you tried out the spark provided aggregations methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will get null counts for all the columns

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, count, col
df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Comment: instead of `count + when`, you can simply `sum`. `sum(col(c).isNotNull())`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it to something like this. First calculate whatever stats you required and assign it to struct (to avoid repetitive for loop). And then transpose columns to rows using `stack` and then extract stats columns from struct. See below example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, struct, round

data = [
    (1, "John", 25, None, "Male"),
    (2, "Jane", None, 5000, "Female"),
    (3, "Bob", 30, 6000, None),
    (4, None, 35, 7000, "Male"),
    (5, "Alice", 40, 8000, "Female"),
]

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "Salary", "Gender"]

# Create a DataFrame with null values
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df.agg(
    *[
        struct(
            (count('*') - count(c)).alias('null_count'),
            round(((count('*') - count(c)) / count('*')) * 100, 2).alias('null_percentage')
        ).alias(f'{c}')
        for c in df.columns
    ]
).selectExpr(
    "stack(" + str(len(df.columns)) + ", " + ", ".join([f"'{c}', {c}" for c in df.columns]) + ") as (column_name, stats)"
).select(
    "column_name",
    "stats.null_count",
    "stats.null_percentage"
).show()

Output:
+-----------+----------+---------------+
|column_name|null_count|null_percentage|
+-----------+----------+---------------+
|         ID|         0|            0.0|
|       Name|         1|            0.2|
|        Age|         1|            0.2|
|     Salary|         1|            0.2|
|     Gender|         1|            0.2|
+-----------+----------+---------------+
```